Residualizing factors in lavaan
Is there a way to perform a regression on a latent variable in lavaan, then save out the residuals of that regression to create a new latent variable of the residuals? So in this example:
LV1 =~ x1 + x2 + x3
LV2 =~ y1 + y2 + y3

LV1 ~ LV2


Is it possible to find and save out to a data frame the residual scores for LV1 ~ LV2 to create another latent variable in another model? Or is there maybe an easier way to do this?
